# Error "Unknown option `AUTO' for package `fontspec-luatex' " when exporting from org to pdf with lualatex

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

When exporting a org file to pdf with `lualatex`, I get the message *PDF file produced with errors.* in my minibuffer. Upon inspection, I find

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `AUTO'  for package `fontspec-luatex'
```

in my LaTeX output. Why is that?

In my configuration, I have `(setq org-latex-compiler "lualatex")` and there is `("AUTO" "fontspec" t ("xelatex" "lualatex")` in `org-latex-packages-alist`. From what I understand, whatever option should passed to fontspec should be determined automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `AUTO` is only used in two cases: for the package `inputenc` where it is replaced by the appropriate coding system, and for the package `babel` (or `polyglossia`) where it is replaced by the appropriate language. It is not a general method of "automaticaly determining options" to an arbitrary package.

Try replacing it with the empty string (or the actual `fontspec` options) in `org-latex-packages-alist`. In no case, should the resulting `.tex` file *ever* contain `AUTO` as an option to a package.

Comment: Indeed, replacing AUTO with empty string fixed it.

Comment: Glad to hear it!